# jquery add class if blank attribute

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a div with a title attribute:

```
<div id="video" title="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>">
```

Basically if the returned value from mysql is blank then I want to add a class. I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#video[title*=""]').addClass('invisible');
});
```

It seems really easy, so don't know what I'm doing wrong.
THanks guys

Comment: Any reason you're doing this in JS?

Answer (score 7):

`*=` means "contains". All of your `title` attributes will contain the empty string. Just change it to `=`:

```
$('#video[title=""]').addClass('invisible');
```

Comment: Thanks mini tech, I'm sure I tried that, but I've changed so many things.... that worked!.

Answer (score 1):

Why do this in javascript?

I assume no title = not wanting to display the video?

```
if( !empty($row_rs_dealItem['video']) ) {
    echo '<div id="video" title="'. $row_rs_dealItem['video'] .'">';
}
```

As pointed out you could use this to add the class if you still want users to load the unused markup...

Answer (score 0):

haven't done this myself but suggest trying

```
if($("#video").attr("title") == "") {
 $("#video").addClass("invisible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do this instead from php

```
echo '<div id="video" title="'. $row_rs_dealItem['video'] .'" class ="'. ((!$row_rs_dealItem['video'])?"invisible":"").'">';
```